# Regex to find a given number of characters after last underscore

Tags: java, regex, schema.yml

I need to find two characters after the last underscore in given filename.

Example string:

```
sample_filename_AB12123321.pdf
```

I am using `[^_]*(?=\.pdf)`, but it finds all the characters after the underscore like `AB12123321`.

I need to find the first two characters `AB` only.

Moreover, there is no way to access the code, I can only modify the regex pattern.

Comment: `.replaceFirst(".*_(.{2}).*", "$1")`? Or match using `.*_(.{2})` / `_([^_]{2})[^_]*$` pattern and grab `matcher.group(1)`.

Comment: Also, why not use `lastIndexOf`? See https://ideone.com/m2tjmt

Comment: I cannot change java code.I need to fix the regex to find the specified characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to solve the problem using a regex you may use:

```
 (?<=_)[^_]{2}(?=[^_]*$)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xgb1Dc/4).

**Details**

- `(?<=_)`  - an underscore must appear immediately to the left of the current position
- `[^_]{2}` - Capturing group 1: any 2 chars other than underscore
- `(?=[^_]*$)` - immediately to the left of the current position, there must appear any 0+ chars other than underscore and then an end of string.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/MfjwF0):

```
String s = "sample_filename_AB12123321.pdf";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=_)[^_]{2}(?=[^_]*$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

Output: `AB`.

Comment: Sorry i am supposed to change only regex.Because of java code is fixed already i could not able to change it to get matcher.group(1)

Comment: @Vicky So, do you mean you need a *matching* pattern that gets the value via `matcher.group(0)`? I modified the answer to accommodate for that requirement.